# Что такое «отголосовать»?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, глаголы, приставка

В общем чате жильцов дома часто употребляется слово "отголосовать", оно вводит меня в некоторое замешательство. Смущает приставка "от", которая обычно означает какое-то действие назад, как, например, *прикатить — откатить, придвинуть — отодвинуть.* И по этой аналогии будет *проголосовать — отголосовать* (то есть отменить то, о чем было проголосовано)...
Из контекста я интуитивно понимаю, что это слово означает "проголосовать".
Получается, что есть какой-то нюанс, который отличает его от слова "проголосовать", но в чем заключается этот нюанс, пока не могу понять.

Примеры из чата:
нужно отголосовать возможность ремонта лифта;
отголосованы строительные работы по замене труб;
отголосовать восстановление за счет капремонта;
тариф отголосован;
дополнительные расходы не предусмотрены, если это не отголосовано на общем собрании.

Answer (score 2):

**ОТ- (ОТО-)** — одна из самых многозначных приставок. Вот её основные значения: *удаление на некоторое расстояние* (отъехать); *отделение части от целого* (отрезать, отломать); *разделение* (отогнать, отодвинуть); *аннулирование* (отменить, отговорить); *ответное действие* (отозваться); ***завершение действия*** (отработать). Можно найти и другие значения, но пока и этих хватит.

Comment: **ОТ(О)-**? Не... Думаю, не пойдёт. Мне *кажется*, что правильно так: **ОТ- (О-)**.

Comment: Признаться, меня в вашем варианте тоже кое-что смущает... Может быть, лучше вот так? —

Comment: Что же именно вас смущает? Считаю, что пробел нужен: ***воз- (вос-, возо-), об- (обо-), от- (ото-)***. https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/648-25_pristavki.html

Comment: А, это было о пробеле! Да, вы правы. Сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 1):

**Мой вывод (по комментариям):**

1. ***Голосовать/отголосовать*** (что?) – это некорректное употребление непереходного глагола ***голосовать/проголосовать*** (за что?)   в качестве переходных глаголов.

Такие формы не очень понятны, непривычны на слух, но **удобны для записи** о проведении голосования.

2. В  данном случае [по словарю](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BE%D1%82&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=42) приставка ***ОТ***  имеет не пространственное значение (отодвинуть), а значение **завершенности** действия.

***Приставка ОТ***

```
  7. Указывает на полное и окончательное завершение 
  тщательно или интенсивно осуществляемого действия 
  или состояния; доведение действия, состояния до 
  какого-л. результата: отремонтировать (часы), 
  отрегулировать (механизм), отыскать (документы).
```

Answer (score 0):

Такого слова в словарях русского языка нет или я не нашёл.

Интуитивно понятно, что в данных фразах "писатели" хотели передать значение "голосование завершилось", "проголосовали за" и тп.

Хотя, такую форму только в шуточных вариантах надписей, ввиду придания слову приставкой ОТ- значения "ну все - конец/приехали", "завершили совсем/с концами", как в словах отжить, отмереть, отмолить и тп. Вот например статья с Пикабу "Нижний Новгород отголосовал", мол, голосование прошло, результаты разочаровали автора текста.

Значение завершения обычного повторяющегося действия у приставки ОТ- есть, когда оно употреблено с формой глагола. Но в данном слове эта приставка не имеет отношения к подобным, как в словах от-работать, от-мыть, ввиду того, что голосовать происходит не от глагола, а от понятия "голосование", то есть это скорее всего "[глагол качественного состояния](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/funktsii-glagolov-kachestvennogo-sostoyaniya-v-dokumentalnoy-proze-xix-nachala-xx-veka-na-materiale-regionalnyh-istochnikov/viewer)", а не обычный глагол действия.

К глаголам качественного состояния относятся глаголы связанные со сложными жизненными или физическими процессами, такие как вращаться - вращение, расти - рост/растение, цвести - цветок/цветение, шуметь - шум, и тп.

Как видно, со всеми этими словами приставка ОТ- не имеет значения обычного завершения действия: отвращать, отрасти, отцвести, отшуметь, - а изменяет общее состояние чего-то. Также слова могут приобретать свойство "отдельности", которое может быть передано одной из форм слова - лететь-отлететь, но отлетать уже имеет совсем другие значение - отлетать в процессе, отлетать совсем. Так что отголосовать в значении "совсем" звучит комично. Кто-то пошутил, что "отголосовать" можно один раз, ну как отжить.

> Отговорила роща золотая
> Березовым, веселым языком,
> И журавли, печально пролетая,
> Уж не жалеют больше ни о ком...

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151909/discussion-on-answer-by----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.